# Renderer2 Angular necessary?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know that Angular uses `Renderer2` class for manipulation our view. It serves as an abstraction layer between provided by angular to allow us manipulate elements of our application without having to touch the `DOM` directly ourselves.

`ElementRef` also is way to manipulate the view but Angular advices us not to use this [because of security reasons.](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) Now it is being using in conjunction with renderer to manipulate the `DOM` like this.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
     selector: '[Randomdirective]' 
})
export class Randomdirective{
   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }
   @HostListener('click') 
   performTask() {
     const li = this.renderer.createElement('li');
     const text = this.renderer.createText('Click here to add li');
     this.renderer.appendChild(li, text);
     this.renderer.appendChild(this.elRef.nativeElement, li);
   }
}
```

I saw from [this source](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/) that renderer is used because:

> this approach makes it  easier to develop apps that can be rendered in environments that don’t have DOM access, like on the server, in a web worker or on native mobile.

If I'm not planning on have my app run in environments that have don't DOM access, would it still be a 'bad practice' to directly manipulate the `DOM` in Angular app?

If so why? (e.g. security/performance reasons?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't going to ssr, it's only bad practice to touch the dom because it's not the angular way, there are way better and more performant ways than appendchild, like *ngFor.. though yes angular does also some sanitation etc.

Comment: sanitation how?

Comment: Like it won't allow you to set innerHTML etc without explicitly saying you trust the source by calling DomSanitizer.trustAsX..

Comment: Nor allow html through interpolation at all.